# Who can set BigQuery custom quota?

Tags: google-bigquery

Let say the billing account created the project and then added an "Is Owner" to the project. 
Can the "Is Owner" request a custom quota limit? 
I am thinking the custom quota limit can be set by the billing account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, being Project Owner is sufficient to request custom quota limit for BigQuery. You just fill [the form](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/bigquery_custom_quota_request_form), it usually takes about 2-3 days until it's processed which is really a shame but I hope it will be improved soon.

Comment: I agree that the 2-3 days to process is a shame when a hot job needed to be done and your quota is up. There is a way around this by cloning the the data into another project (if project quota) or have another user does the query (if project quota hasn't reach but user has). 
I'll investigate more on this answer and will accept it later.

Comment: Haven't try it but I believe this is true as quota is per project and for each user for that project.